# Forward support email address to gmail using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, gmail, email-forwarding

I have a rails application hosted on my domain. I want to set up support@mydomain.com, which would just forward messages to the admins of the domain. Essentially it's just an alias for a group of people, the admins of the website.

Currently I set it up so that support is a "user" of the account. Me and the other admins are also "users", and I pay for the support email monthly. I find it inefficient since it should only serve as a alias that forwards (redirects) emails, and not serve as an extra account.

Is there anyone who knows how I could either set it up in my rails application, or knows how to change it in my DNS (Network Solutions) or my server host (Heroku)? (I am a starter in this)

I think it's a basic question, but I would really appreciate if anyone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You set it up with your DNS provider. Follow this tutorial.
http://www.networksolutions.com/support/how-can-i-forward-my-mail/